# Echo the UTC time

Tags: javascript, echo, utc

I have this vendor-supplied script that retrieves the UTC time from the vendor's server.

```
<script>
var button = $('button[api_access_id]');
$.getJSON('https://sandbox.forte.net/checkout/getUTC?callback=?').done(function (utc) {
button.attr('utc_time', utc);
});
</script>
```

I want to just echo the UTC time to the browser window.

How do i do?

Comment: Can you specify where to echo utc inside some element, or you just want to check the value ?

Comment: Hi @loki. I just want to check the value. I'm comparing this javascript value to UTC calculated in other languages like PHP and Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can alert it to browser window like this(if utc from get request is string not object or array)

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://sandbox.forte.net/checkout/getUTC?callback=?').done(function(utc) {
    window.alert(utc);
  })
</script>
```

***Note:*** you don't need even run this in your app, you can test it directy from console, if you open browser inspector. And in console tab paste

```
$.getJSON('https://sandbox.forte.net/checkout/getUTC?callback=?').done(function(utc) {
    window.alert(utc);
  })
```